# Lazy forward reference in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to Haskell and reading the [Arrow tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Arrow_tutorial).
I can't understand how Haskell evaluates this `loop` function:

```
newtype Circuit a b = Circuit { unCircuit :: a -> (Circuit a b, b) }
instance ArrowLoop Circuit where
    loop (Circuit cir) = Circuit $ \b ->
        let (cir', (c,d)) = cir (b,d) -- line (A)
        in  (loop cir', c)
```

At `line (A)`, variable `d` is used before initialization.
How is this possible? Does GHC perform a fixed-point computation?

Comment: This is similar to the classical Haskell fibonacci function: `let fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. Here fibs is used in its own definition (which in other languages is often only doable with recursive functions, values can't be self recursive without using pointers explicitly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell's `let` and `where` bindings are self recursive. You could model that elimination exactly by using a fixed point computation. Since `ArrowLoop` models exactly a function which folds in on itself you would expect a need to use this self recursion.

As always, self-recursion like this might be non-terminating unless it can be evaluated sufficiently lazily to be productive.